# this[functionName] in an es6 class function cause "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type string can't be used to index"

Tags: typescript, es6-class

I'm trying to create a command like service using es6 classes like so:

```
class Person {
    run(){
        console.log("running");
    }
    walk(){
        console.log("walking");
    }
    talk(){
        console.log("talking");
    }
    execute(name: string){
       this[name]()
    }
}

const me = new Person();

me.execute('run');
me.execute('walk');
me.execute('talk');
```

This is completely valid but typescript is barking on `this[name]` part:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Person'.
```

How do I define the "name" parameter in this case to be a class member type of Person?

Comment: if `name` is any arbitrary string then what are the assurances that it will work on the specific context?

Comment: It's not valid, Typescript is correctly telling you that your parameter of type `string` cannot be used to index your object, because it doesn't have an index signature. If you want the parameter to only be `'run' | 'walk' | 'talk'` then you have to declare that type - not `string`. As general advice, if you take the attitude that errors are the compiler's fault then you will not get very far as a programmer.

Comment: Check out Guerric's P answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the key could be any of the class keys except `execute` itself, you could define the parameter type as follows:

```
execute(name: Exclude<keyof Person, 'execute'>){
   this[name]();
}
```

You can see it in action on this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGn6iArmgBQCUO%20V0w6qI8AdCCgOYkBERaaAlmqw5kA3LnwBfMXgDuYEAGtylanlpp6TFuw6yF-QSKnRJVAC5zFFI1TUbmbTub0ChoqifzwAHvGCFT8CRoYAC28ABc0ACiXqCEACbwADzy8ACeKABmcEioaAA00ADk3r7%208EUAfFYq0KYAFrwQANrBYQC65G4S2JLYtqbQYdAAvNBo8NI5yOhd2NhhjKV%20ASRF3EWGi8vla7rym6LbPiuBRU4HIkA).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Define the **name type** as follows

```js
execute(name: "talk" | "walk" | "run") {
    this[name]()
}
```